# how to convert all json path key to capital letter in jway java json parser?

Tags: java, jsonpath

I need to convert all my json path key to capital letter in jway json parser

aven dependency com.jayway.jsonpath json-path 2.3.0

Comment: Hi Nizamudeen, you should make your own attempt first and share it here and tell us where it's going wrong.

Comment: @notyou could not find the api to convert it.